# Ioncube include_file_protection

Tags: php, include, ioncube

I have a question about include_file_protection in ioncube.

Is it possible to dissallow nonencoded files to include encoded files but allow encoded files to include nonencoded files? The file i want to include has the extension ".cache"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, however you could do the following:

A encoded with include attack protection enabled
B encoded without include attack protection but with the relevant property set so as to allow inclusion by A
C non encoded.

B can include C and C could include B, however A and any others using include attack protection could not interact with C directly. In this scenario, B would typically be just a thin delegation wrapper to bridge between A and C.

For more details it is recommended to contact ionCube support: http://ioncu.be/S

disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: Can you please explain about what is "with the relevant property set" ? I do facing the same scenario of A and other files. Getting the error as unauthorised file!!

Comment: If using the GUI, set include attack protection in a project and then use the view command line option. You'll see that a property is set with the attack protection key using --property. That's the property that you must set on file B so that it can be included successfully.